# Redraw Image on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, frontend

I'm developing a painting game and I need to redraw a image on canvas in each frame. The problem is the image keeps getting thicker everytime I redraw it. Why doesn't it draw the same pixels?

Here is an example of what I'm saying, just click in redraw 50 times and notice the difference:

https://codepen.io/ziron/pen/bGEzYjq

```
function drawImage(){
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

function draw50times(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    drawImage();
  }
}

function clearCanvas(){
  console.log("Clear")
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawImage();
}
```

PS: I can't use  ctx.clearRect because I would lose the rest of my canvas.

**After I draw image once:**
[image: Before I Redraw]

**After I draw image 50 times:**
[image: After I Redraw]

Comment: The PNG has semitransparent pixels; these accumulate when you draw them over and over, creating that effect. You need to solve a different problem though: fix your code so you *can* use clearRect in between. (A quick and dirty fix is to remove all semitransparent pixels from that PNG, for instance by turning it into a [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/kDGl06J.gif) where only full-white is transparent; this should also "fix" the issue)

Comment: You can also position the image above the canvas, that way you can draw on the canvas as much as you like and the lineart will always appear on top; no need to clear or redraw anything.

Comment: But I have a paint bucket tool (flood fill). I need to read the image pixels to make that work

Comment: You should be able to do both, i.e. redraw on the canvas but show the image on top; although that might add the pixels together again; still, to use floodfill you need aliased lineart anyway.